# Numpy: apply along axis with input arrays with different indicies

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a problem where I have two spatial datasets, 1) temperature (`temp`), and 2) depth(`sd`) that need to be combined in a calculation.  The metric I am calculating `cfgi` metric for the first day (i.e. t=0) is to be initialized as all zeros.  Each subsequent day (i.e. t=1) is calculated as:

```
cfgi = cfgi_t=0 - temp_t=1 * np.exp(-0.2*sd_t=1)
```

where `t=0` or `t=1` should be interpreted as a subscript

Lets say I have these data, where axis=0 represents daily surfaces:

```
temp = np.array([-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -2.,
       -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2.,
       -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -3., -3.,
       -3., -3., -3., -3., -3., -3., -3., -3., -3., -3., -3., -3., -3.,
       -3., -3., -3., -3., -3., -3., -3., -3., -3., -3., -4., -4., -4.,
       -4., -4., -4., -4., -4., -4., -4., -4., -4., -4., -4., -4., -4.,
       -4., -4., -4., -4., -4., -4., -4., -4., -4., -5., -5., -5., -5.,
       -5., -5., -5., -5., -5., -5., -5., -5., -5., -5., -5., -5., -5.,
       -5., -5., -5., -5., -5., -5., -5., -5.]).reshape((5,5,5))

sd = np.array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.,
       2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3.,
       3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.,
       3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.,
       4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 5., 5.,
       5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.,
       5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.]).reshape(5,5,5)

cfgi = np.zeros(sd.shape)
```

My first idea was to use `np.apply_along_axis` with this function:

```
def calculate_CFGI(a):
    return a[0] - a[1]* np.exp(-0.2*a[2])
```

This works, but I am hoping someone could help me achieve my desired result without a for-loop.

```
for i in range(sd.shape[0]-1):
    c = cfgi[i,:,:]
    t = temp[i+1,:,]
    s = sd[i+1,:,]
    combined = np.stack([c,t,s])
    cfgi[i+1,:,:] = np.apply_along_axis(calculate_CFGI, 0, combined)
```

Desired Result:

```
array([[[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]],

       [[1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009],
        [1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009],
        [1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009],
        [1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009],
        [1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009, 1.34064009]],

       [[2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  ],
        [2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  ],
        [2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  ],
        [2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  ],
        [2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  , 2.987075  ]],

       [[4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086],
        [4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086],
        [4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086],
        [4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086],
        [4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086, 4.78439086]],

       [[6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806],
        [6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806],
        [6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806],
        [6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806],
        [6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806, 6.62378806]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your relation carefully:

```
 cfgi[0, ...] = 0
 cfgi[1, ...] = 0 - temp[1, ...] * np.exp(-0.2 * sd[1, ...])
 cfgi[2, ...] = 0 - temp[1, ...] * np.exp(-0.2 * sd[1, ...]) - temp[2, ...] * np.exp(-0.2 * sd[2, ...])
 ...
```

You can say x = `temp * np.exp(0.2 * sd)`, and write:

```
cfgi[n, ...] = 0 - x[1, ...] - x[2, ...] - ... - x[n, ...]
```

Hopefully you can see the pattern here:

```
cfgi = np.zeros_like(temp)
cfgi[1:, ...] = -np.cumsum(temp[1:, ...] * np.exp(-0.2 * sd[1:, ...]), axis=0)
```

Comment: What does `...` mean as an index of `cfgi`?

Comment: @dubbbdan. `...` is an `Ellipsis` object, which means "`:` as many times as necessary". We could equally well write `[x, :, :]` in this case.

Comment: This is great.  Thanks!